# Driving 100W COB From mains using discrete components I have on hand

Tags: led, current-source, led-driver, cob

I was wondering if I could realistically drive a 100w COB directly from mains using a bunch of discrete components that I already have on hand.

I have a bunch of BJTs MOSFETs and E cores and I want to build a circuit to run 1-4 COBs in series using a current sink directly from rectified mains voltage with no isolation. My reasoning is that they sell 50w COBs that plug directly into mains voltage on amazon that use very inefficient linear regulation, so why not make a switching regulator directly from mains and call it a day?

Here is the circuit I designed in LTSpice.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvEuyh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there a better way to tighten up the current control, because when I simulate this circuit in LTSpice and I can't seem to get the current down to 3A, the lowest current I've seen was 3.6A which was like 125W (DEAD COB). If this idea isn't completely insane, how can I get the current down to 3A so that I can actually test this thing in reality where I wont have to risk killing 2 COBs in series?

**Final Edit**

The solution was R36, apparently the resistor was necessary to limit current enough to reset the latch cleanly, like in the case of a BJT RS flip-flop, where each transistor has a base resistor and the base of either transistor has to be pulled directly to ground for a period to enact function.

Comment: Your design is irrelevant without design specs that include RdsOn, ESR, DCR, f and layout.  You have far too much latency & complexity in BJT’s to control current with loss in GBW and thus PWM control

Comment: My microscope is out for cleaning.  Please post a readable image.

Comment: @AnalogKid Maybe you should take that up with Circuit lab, I didn't make the image or perhaps click on the link and view the circuit properly?

Comment: Circuit is awfully complicated! You could use a hysteretic buck or a constant off-time, it would be simpler...

Comment: @bobflux The circuit is certainly a bowl of noodles, but with the COVID and all of the time I have on my hands, it's something to do. The circuit started out as a hysteretic version of this current sink, but the pulse at the gate looked really nasty so I had to add a flipflop to clean it up, then somehow the circuit evolved into this. Though when I actually build it, I'll probably use an LM339.

Comment: You're monitoring the current with a resistor in the FET source which is only in circuit when the FET is ON, which means this should be a constant OFF time converter, not a hysteretic... Hysteretic buck has the current sense resistor in circuit all the time, which is difficult to do here.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me but what is a COB?

Comment: @bobflux I believe a hysteretic converter relies on feedback from the sense resistor via comparator as opposed to an amplifier to switch the FET gate and not a predefined frequency, or did I totally misunderstand the guys at TI?

Comment: @mhaselup a COB (Chip On Board)  is an array of LEDs, do a search on google, it's pretty easy to find.

Comment: The comments here seem a bit jejune

Comment: Hysteretic buck means a comparator with hysteresis monitors the sense resistor and drives the FET, so inductor current ripples around the value corresponding to comparator threshold, with ripple determined by hysteresis, and frequency is variable. But this circuit here only monitors the sense resistor when the FET is on, which means it's not a hysteretic buck...

Comment: Here the sense resistor is only in circuit when the FET is ON. On the plus side, it only dissipates power when the FET is ON, which reduces losses. On the minus side, current is not monitored when the FET is OFF because voltage on sense resistor is zero. It is also not possible to regulate average current, only peak current. So, a comparator to turn off the FET when current reaches a threshold, which means it regulates peak current. To turn on the FET, you can either use an oscillator and a RS flop, which gives a constant frequency, or a monostable that creates a constant off-time for the FET.

Comment: @bobflux I'm aware this circuit is not hysteretic in nature, because it uses an oscillator. I'm not arguing that. Read what I said. It was hysteretic before i posted it here, This project started it that way, but I added an oscillator because I didn't like the pulse at the gate. There were too many switching losses so I added an oscillator.

Comment: What was the problem with the pulse at the gate?

Comment: @bobflux It had a nasty rise and fall, so I had to add a flipflop and Schmitt trigger, which was more convoluted and I still didn't have really tight control over the current, being this is a mains application, I opted for the oscillator. Now that I've added the resistor to the latch, it's steady at 2.89A with a Vref of 14mV. .014V/005ohms=2.8A, which means it's off by 90mA. I think I can live with that.

Comment: @user14828 I am aware of what COB means in a general context, I have not seen it used to describe high power LEDs hence the question. If I was asking this I would avoid terminology that clouds the question and call an LED an LED.

Comment: @mhaselup Sorry, my intention was not to offend you by being condescending. However, you did only ask, "what is a COB?", which would indicate that you didn't know what the acronym was at all. 
As far as the jejune comments, I was talking about the first two comments, where the first didn't even deserve a reply and the second one who said his microscope was in the shop, where Circuit Lab obviously produced the image and there is clearly a link leading to a full sized image of the schematic. Sorry again.

Comment: @user14828 No worries. Thanks for clarifying.